# Looking for a set of tools/objects to start a website in PHP

Tags: php

Looking for a good set of base objects to start a website up in PHP.  I am not looking for links to CakePHP as I am not interested in frameworks.  I am looking for a set of objects that would come handy to start off with for new projects.

Objects such as:

- Loggers
- MySQL wrapper object
- etc

Basically a "Start with this", I remember seeing a nice collection of objects and code on Digg, but I can't find it again.  There were user objects (for logging in), fsck editor built in, etc.

Comment: Zend to the Rescue! (forget my "Not interested in frameworks...")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MySQL wrapper object

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo).

> I am not interested in frameworks

Well, you are. You are not looking for a tightly coupled, full stack framework perhaps.

You might find one or more of the following useful:

- [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [ezComponents](http://ez.no/ezcomponents)

They are all very loosely coupled frameworks, where you can pick and match as you need it.

Comment: hmm, I've been looking at Zend... seems it is exactly what I want.  I've been against frameworks all this time... and they are exactly what I wanted... in this case, ignorance is NOT bliss, lol.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's a  bunch of digg related code found here.

http://github.com/digg/

I also don't understand why you don't want to use a framework, but want to use all the components that make a framework. That didn't make much sense to me.

I would look into the Zend Framework. Before you scream at me for recommending it, a lot of the components are modular which means you can take the bits you need.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/

**PS** : Although Zend Framework has "framework" in the title, a lot of people see it as a collection of classes. So check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Frameworks by their very definition are a set of objects that come in handy when starting a new project.

PDO can give you database abstraction without resorting to third-party libraries. Templating can be accomplished with the alternate syntax (`foreach():`) and short tags (`<?= $var ?>`). You can do it all yourself if you want, just keep the docs up and get crackin' redefining that wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I can certainly recommend Zend Framework for this purpose. As a glue framework you can use as many or as few of the components as you like, with or without the MVC.